# SQL Server - Message 145, but item is in the select List

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following Query

```
select DISTINCT ID, field1, field2 
from MyTable 
where field1 = 'myValue' OR field2 = 'myValue'
order by case when field1 = 'myValue' THEN 1 else 2 end
```

gives this error:

> Server: Msg 145, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 ORDER BY items must appear
>   in the select list if  SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

which seems weird, since field1 obviously IS in the select List.

What is the reason and how can I change that?

(I am sure there is a workaround, but for the time being I want to keep at least the `order by` section)

Comment: you have no `WHERE` in your query

Comment: sorry, just edited

Comment: What is expected output with table data?

Comment: the condition ordered by the `order by`

Comment: A table has _columns_, not fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using `distinct`, you can't use anything in the `order by` clause that does not appear in exactly the same way in the `select` clause (except for ordinal positions in the order by clause, but I wouldn't recommend using that, ever).

If your `select` clause contains a case expression, you can use the same case expression in your `order by` clause - but you can't use a case expression in your `order by` clause if it's missing in the `select` clause, even if it only contains column names that exists in the `select` clause.

There are basically two ways you can solve this. 
One is to replace the `distinct` with `group by`:

```
select ID, field1, field2 
from MyTable 
where field1 = 'myValue' OR field2 = 'myValue'
group by ID, field1, field2 
order by case when field1 = 'myValue' THEN 1 else 2 end
```

and the other one is to use a derived query or a cte for the distinct, and order by in the outer query (I'll show the derived query since the other answer showed the cte option):

```
select * 
from 
(
    select DISTINCT ID, field1, field2 
    from MyTable 
    where field1 = 'myValue' OR field2 = 'myValue'
) x
order by case when field1 = 'myValue' THEN 1 else 2 end
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/CCOE73402)

Comment: @Pரதீப் I accept your correction, will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Pரதீப் edited. I suspect this is turned my answer a bit more cumbersome but at least now it's more accurate. Thanks!

Comment: Looks better now ;)